# I want to see all the columns as a result of the minus operation

Tags: sql, plsql

table1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | New York |
| B | Istanbul |
| B | London |

table2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | New York |
| B | Istanbul |
| C | London |

```
SELECT Column A From Table1
minus
SELECT Column A From Table2
```

RESULT -> C

I want to see result row so not only columnA

RESULT -> C LONDON

How can i handle it?

Comment: Why to use MINUS here? That's just a NOT EXISTS use case, SELECT columnA, columnB
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT columnA, columnB FROM table1 t1
   WHERE t1.columnA = t2.columnA AND t2.columnB = t1.columnB);

Comment: Why not select both columns and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (cola, colb) as
  3    (select 'A', 'New York' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'Istanbul' from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 'London'   from dual
  6    ),
  7  table2 (cola, colb) as
  8    (select 'A', 'New York' from dual union all
  9     select 'B', 'Istanbul' from dual union all
 10     select 'C', 'London'   from dual
 11    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  select b.*
 13  from table2 b
 14  where not exists (select null
 15                    from table1 a
 16                    where a.cola = b.cola
 17                   );

C COLB
- --------
C London

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move that select to the where clause of your query, as follows:

```
SELECT Column B FROM table 
  WHERE Column A IN (
SELECT Column A From Table
minus
SELECT Column A From Table
)
```

Comment: Is there a solution to use like this

SELECT Column B FROM table 
  WHERE Column A like (%
SELECT Column A From Table
minus
SELECT Column A From Table
%)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. ```LIKE``` expects a scalar value and the result of a ```MINUS``` operation can be a resultset. Please update your question with an example and expected results

Answer (score 0):

This is the most optimal query for it :
have proper indexes on columnA either `btree`(high selectivity) or `bitmap`(low  selectivity)

```
select b.* from 
table2 b left join table1 a 
on b.ColumnA=a.ColumnA
where a.ColumnA is null;
```

`in` will be very slow if the tables cardinality is very large so Koen Lostrie answer is not optimal.

Littlefoot's answer is based on `subquery` which is also slower !!